# Rails: How to find same model association records with no associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :super_account, class_name: 'Account', optional: true, foreign_key: 'account_id'
  has_many   :sub_accounts,  class_name: 'Account'
end
```

What would be the rails way to find all accounts with no sub_accounts?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Account.left_joins(:sub_accounts)
       .where(sub_accounts_accounts: { id: nil })
```

`sub_accounts_accounts` is what the joined table is aliased as in the query:

```
SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "accounts" "sub_accounts_accounts" 
  ON "sub_accounts_accounts"."account_id" = "accounts"."id" 
WHERE "sub_accounts_accounts"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1
```

`.left_joins` (aka left outer joins) was introduced in Rails 5. In Rails 4 you need to [use `.joins` with a sql string](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html).

```
Account.joins(%q{
  LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts sub_accounts
  ON sub_accounts.account_id = accounts.id
}).where(sub_accounts: { id: nil })
```

Comment: agree with this solution, but it can be written as a scope
`scope :no_sub_account, -> { left_joints... }`

Comment: I agree with this, especially as it does not require a second model to be created for the child objects, its purely self referential.

Comment: @Thang of course it could be written as a scope but that would just add noise to the example.

Answer (score 1):

The Rails way is to add `:counter_cache` to this associations. [How to](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache)

So you need to add column `sub_accounts_count` to `Account`
And add `counter_cache: true` in model `SubAccount`

```
belongs_to :account, counter_cache: true
```

After this you can just call `Account.where(sub_accounts_count: 0)` as example.

Comment: Counter-caches are just one solution and come with the cost of an extra write query and can be prone to race conditions. They are not "the Rails way".